# Why horizontal form is not showing elements horizontally?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My razor code has generated something like this:

```
<div class="container col-sm-4" style="background-color: wheat">
  <form action="/AwfulSite/Search/Index" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="FirstName" style="text-align: right">FirstName</label>
      <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

But why is it showing the label on a new line? I want them to be horizontal next to each other and I have defined the form as horizontal too

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is a subtle one - you've tried to use a `.form-control` element as a column, which interferes with how Bootstrap's scaffolding system is designed. Looking at the styles that `.form-control` applies, one is `width:100%`, which will make the element wider than what a `.col-sm-10` should be (which is why it breaks to the next line).

Looking at the [documentation example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal), they get around this by nesting the `.form-control` inside a `<div>`, and making that containing `<div>` the column instead. So revising your code accordingly:

```
<div class="container col-sm-4" style="background-color: wheat">
  <form action="/AwfulSite/Search/Index" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="FirstName" style="text-align: right">FirstName</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's an [example Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/FenlOTiv9F). Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks,I didn't understand this sentence : "and make the container element the column instead."  Do you mean the new DIV is the container element ?

Comment: Yeah, @Bohn. I'll clarify the wording to make it easier to understand, glad I could help out anyways!